# How to set textbox value inside bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am showing bootstrap popover upon clicking on Anchor element as follows.

**Jquery**

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
            trigger: 'click',
            placement: "top",
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return $('#popover-content').html();
            }
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="txtContent" type="text" />
        <button id="btnOk" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;
        </button>
        <button id="btnCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<a href='#' class='btn-link' data-html='true' data-toggle='popover'>Sample text</a>
```

I want to set textbox value(text) which is inside popover to same as anchor element's text (i.e. 'Sample text' here). Can someone please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `content` use `this` which is the element reference from where the popover is invoked. So here `this` would be the anchor element in your scenario. Get the text from the `anchor` tag and `add the value attribute` to your `input element` and then return `$('#popover-content').html()`.

Check the below code snippet. This might help you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: "bottom",
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      var anchorText = $(this).text();
      $('#popover-content').find('input[id=txtContent]').attr('value', anchorText);
      return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="txtContent" type="text" />
      <button id="btnOk" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;
      </button>
      <button id="btnCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href='#' class='btn-link' data-html='true' data-toggle='popover'>Sample text</a>
  <script>
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Works perfectly man ! Thank you so much. Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

As docs says, if you would like to show HTML in popover, you have to pass HTML through `title` argument, so in your case it stands for:

```
<a href='#' class='btn-link' data-html='true' data-toggle='popover'
data-title="Sample text">Sample text</a>
```

Comment: data-title is used to show title on top of the popover. I want to set the text of control inside popover